# Is it bad for the MacBook Pro if I use its speakers with the lid closed?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I am curious whether using the MacBook Pro speakers with the lid closed is somehow detrimental to the screen resting above it?

(I have an external monitor plugged in to my shiny new MBP 14" 2021, so the lid is usually closed.)

Does anyone know if there's any information about this? I have scoured the Internet but haven't been able to find an answer.

Comment: What leads you to believe it might be detrimental?

Comment: I think he means the speakers blowing soundwaves at the (glass?) screen...

Comment: @Tetsujin I dunno, magnets interacting, sound waves against fiber glass, some other components underneath, this might sound like a silly question but I rather ask than be sorry.

Comment: @dkugappi I was asking myself the same thing right now. Did you get any solid answers anywhere else? :)

Comment: @DarkoAtanasov I actually just called apple to ask, and the person I spoke with said it’s okay. Not sure of whether that was an expert answer though.